Preventing Loops in a Partner-User Relationship in SQL Schema and any optimization suggestion
I'm working on a SQL schema where users can be linked to partners through a relationship table. My goal is to prevent certain types of relationships that would create loops or allow a user to belong to multiple partners. Here's my current schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "username" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "email" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "password" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "role" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CHECK (role IN ('admin', 'partner', 'user')),
    "phone_number" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    "address_id" INT NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP,
    "deleted_at" TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES addresses(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "partners_users" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "partner_id" INT NOT NULL,
    "user_id" INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "linked_at" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP,
    "deleted_at" TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

Goal:

A user should not be linked to more than one partner.

There should be no loops in the partner-user relationship, i.e., the following is not allowed:


Example: Partner 1 links to User 2, then Partner 2 links to User 3, but Partner 3 linking back to Partner 1 is forbidden as it creates a loop.
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 1  -- This should be blocked as it creates a loop.

My Approach:

I enforce the unique constraint on the user_id in the partners_users table to prevent a user from being linked to more than one partner.

To prevent loops, I plan to recursively fetch all linked partners and check if there is already a path between the new partner and the existing partner. If a path is found, I will block the insertion.
for above example i look for the path between 3 -> 1


Questions:

Is my approach of recursively checking the paths between partners to prevent loops a valid solution?
Are there any potential performance concerns with this approach, especially if the table grows large?
Would there be any optimization techniques (e.g., restructuring the table) that could make this approach more efficient?
Is there a more efficient algorithmic approach to preventing loops in such a relationship structure?


Start with your queries, for example, a recursive common table expression: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE

If a user can only have one partner then why not make partner a FK on the user table? It’s not clear, to me, what the difference between a user and a partner is, as they both reference the same user table - a user can only have one partner but a partner can be linked to multiple users?

"...Example: Partner 1 links to User 2, then Partner 2 links to User 3..." -- That already violates your first rule: user #2 is linked to two other users (#1 and #3). Please elaborate on your first rule.

It's not necessary to fetch all linked partners: it will be adequate to search only those that are ancestors of the candidate insertion row. One optimization would be to check if the user of the candidate insertion row is a partner in any of the existing rows since a loop can only exist if the user is a partner to another user. This check could be one of the conditions used in the initialization part of the recursive query.

@NickW You're absolutely right in noticing that both the user and partner reference the same users table. The key difference is in the roles they play in the hierarchy. You can think of the partner-to-user link as something similar to Multi-Level Marketing (MLM), where a partner (or senior) can have multiple users under them, but each user can only report to one partner. Essentially, the relationship is hierarchical.
A user today could become a partner tomorrow and have their own set of users under them

@TheImpaler a partner can have multiple users, but a user can only have one partner. Additionally, a user can become a partner in the future. I realize now that the "user_id" INT NOT NULL UNIQUE in the partners_users table might be misleading because the name user_id doesn't clearly indicate that this could refer to either a user or a partner. I should probably rename it to something more meaningful, like sub_partner_id or subordinate_id, to avoid confusion.
